# Why does an empty command not return an empty string?

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I want to check if a command returns something or not. I tried the following but it is not working. Why is the output of the following code `false`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\emptystring}{}

\begin{document}
  \ifstrempty{\emptystring}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Manual: "Expands to `true` if the `string` is empty, and to `false` otherwise. The `string` is not expanded in the test." The `string` still contains `\emptystring` and not nothing. The `xstring` package expands all its arguments: `\IfStrEq{\emptystring}{}{true}{false}`.

Comment: Or use the other tests in `etoolbox`, I mostly use `\ifdefempty` or `\ifdefvoid`. When reading the manual note that your use here is `\ifstrempty{<command>}` a `<command>` is not the same as a string.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: If you write an answer I would check it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `etoolbox` manual states:

> Expands to `true` if the `string` is empty, and to `false` otherwise. The `string` is not expanded in the test.

The `string` still contains `\emptystring` and not nothing.

You probably want `\ifdefempty` or `\ifdefvoid` which acts on control sequences and not *strings*, depending on your use-case.

---

I've added an L3 test with `\str_if_empty:nTF` which works similar to `\ifstrempty` but I'm using `\exp_args:No` to expand the argument `o`nce before it get's forwarded to `\str_if_empty`.

Yes,

```
\exp_args:No \ifstrempty {\emptystring}{true}{false}
```

would do the same.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\emptystring}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\IFSTREMPTY{m}{
  \exp_args:No \str_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  etoolbox \texttt{ifstrempty}: \ifstrempty{\emptystring}{true}{false}
  
  etoolbox \texttt{ifdefempty}: \ifdefempty{\emptystring}{true}{false}

  etoolbox \texttt{ifdefvoid}: \ifdefvoid{\emptystring}{true}{false}
      
  L3: \IFSTREMPTY{\emptystring}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Why not use one of the other `etoolbox` tests instead of loading `xstring`.

Comment: @daleif Do you mean `\ifdefempty`? Because I didn't know it exists.

Comment: That or `\ifdefvoid`, they are meant to be used on macros

Comment: @daleif I've added these to my answer (and removed `xstring` it wasn't meant to be the real answer to begin with). It will all depend on what the actual test is. `\emptystring` could contain only `\empty` and the test might lead to yet another unexpected `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do.

Do you want just to test whether the first level expansion of the token you pass is empty? So

```
\ifstremptyonelevel{\emptystring}{true}{false}
\ifstremptyonelevel{\notemptystring}{true}{false}
```

would return true and false with, respectively,

```
\newcommand{\emptystring}{}
\newcommand{\notemptystring}{\empty}
```

Or do you want to pursue recursive expansion? With this choice the test

```
\ifstremptyfull{\emptystring}{true}{false}
\ifstremptyfull{\notemptystring}{true}{false}
```

would return true in both cases.

But the second test would require care about what kind of material you intend to pass. Performing full expansion on something that contains, say, `\textbf{x}` would wreak havoc.

Let's leave the second kind of test aside and restrict to one level expansion.

You can use `expl3` rather than the `etoolbox` tests.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstremptyTF}{mmm}
 {
  \str_if_empty:oTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstremptyT}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_empty:oT { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstremptyF}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_empty:oF { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstremptyp}{m}
 {
  \str_if_empty_p:o { #1 }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_empty:n { o } { p,T,F,TF }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\emptystring}{}
\newcommand{\notemptystring}{\empty}

\begin{document}

\ifstremptyTF{}{true}{false}

\ifstremptyTF{a}{true}{false}

\ifstremptyTF{\emptystring}{true}{false}

\ifstremptyTF{\notemptystring}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

I also defined the shorthands `\ifstremptyT` and `\ifstremptyF` in case the true or false text are empty.

This will print

> true
> false
> true
> false

What's the last command `\ifstremptyp`? It's the predicate form. You can define an interface to the `\bool_if:nTF` function.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifbooleanTF}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstremptyTF}{mmm}
 {
  \str_if_empty:oTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstremptyT}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_empty:oT { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstremptyF}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_empty:oF { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstremptyp}{m}
 {
  \str_if_empty_p:o { #1 }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_empty:n { o } { p,T,F,TF }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\emptystring}{}
\newcommand{\notemptystring}{\empty}

\begin{document}

\ifbooleanTF{\ifstremptyp{\emptystring} && \ifstremptyp{\notemptystring}}{true}{false}

\ifbooleanTF{\ifstremptyp{\emptystring} || \ifstremptyp{\notemptystring}}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

This uses the logic connectives “and” and “or” respectively. The first test will return false, the second one true.